# Double Entries Made in Database for Button Clicked

Tags: javascript, php

I was building a Affiliate Website and i need to keep a track when the user clicks the submit button or image i.e a entry in db with time should be made when such things occur.But to the dismay double entries are being made,I.e when i redirect to bhejo.php from new.php a entry is made and when i click submit and page redirects to amazon another entry is made.Please Help.Stuck.

```
<?php require_once("navig.php");
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) { ?>
<?php
$cool=$_SESSION['user_id'];
echo '<a href="http://www.amazon.in/?tag=rewardadda-21&param=$cool"><img src=images/a.png></a>';
?>
<script>
$("#a").click(function() {
   alert("Entry added"); 
    <?php
    require_once('connect.php');
    $dbb = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
        or die('Error communicating to MySQL server.');
        $cool_id=$_SESSION['user_id'];

$querye = "INSERT INTO orderdata(user_id, store_used) ".
                        "VALUES ('$cool_id', 'amazon')";
mysqli_query ($dbb, $querye);                       
mysqli_close($dbb);                     
    ?>
});
    </script>
<?php
    }
else {
?>
<div id="damn">
You need to be logged in to view this. Redirecting you to Log In page in 5 seconds (<a href="logsign.php">click here if it doesn't redirect automatically</a>).</div>
<script>
setTimeout(function () {
   window.location.href= "logsign.php"; // the redirect goes here
},5000);
</script>

<?php
}
require_once('footer.php');
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP is a server side language, you cannot simply append it to Javascript which is a Client Side Language. When someone requests a page, the server first processes the PHP code, and then sends the HTML Doc. The reason you are getting double entries is because on page load, the PHP code has already been executed. Thus clicking the 'submit' type button most likely only refreshed the page. Either use the classic form action attribute, or use ajax

```
<script>
    $("#a").click(function() { <-- JAVASCRIPT
       alert("Entry added");  //These two languages are executed at seperate times
        <?php <--PHP
        require_once('connect.php');
        $dbb = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
            or die('Error communicating to MySQL server.');
            $cool_id=$_SESSION['user_id'];

    $querye = "INSERT INTO orderdata(user_id, store_used) ".
                            "VALUES ('$cool_id', 'amazon')";
    mysqli_query ($dbb, $querye);                       
    mysqli_close($dbb);                     
        ?>
    });
        </script>
```

**Resolution Method:**
The most simple way would be to use the "action=" form attribute. Thus on form submit, you can specify the script to execute:

```
<form action='script.php'>

<input type='submit' ...>//<-- script.php will execute when you click that button
</form>
```

The other way is to use AJAX: (jQuery is preferable)

```
$.ajax({
url:"script.php",
type: "POST",
data:{name:value, name:value},
success: function (){},
...
})
```

AJAX DOC: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Can i use $_Get instead of Js to make entry in db.If Yes,How?

Comment: A GET Request does not work either, if someone refreshes the page, the code will execute again. You run into the same problem of multiple entries.

Comment: I am saying that for ex  you visited y page from x there is a button/image there with the url where it should ultimately redirect to.So how to extract user id with the time  from the redirected url using get

Comment: GET requests work with the link, you'll need to use `$id = $_GET["id"]`. Then format the link like this `www.mysite.com/page.php?id=<userid>`